# Ask.com sitemap crawler down (for good)?

Tags: search-engines, sitemap, web-crawlers, ping

I have been using `Ask.com` as one of the search engines to ping my sitemap. When I went to ping my sitemap today to have my sitemap re-indexed, the website (http://submissions.ask.com/ping) says it no longer exists? I did a DNS lookup on `submissions.ask.com` and it looks like `Ask.com` has removed the subdomain, but their [Website Crawler FAQ](http://www.ask.com/about/help/webmasters) still has it listed? Any ideas of whats happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We now utilize a crawling method of adding new content to our search index. The subdomain you refer to was just retired over the weekend, and we'll be updating that FAQ page very shortly.

Best regards,
Eric from `Ask.com`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was wondering what happened to Ask.com's sitemap submission tool.

Comment: Any update on this ? is there a new url for sitemap ping ?

Answer (score 2):

`Ask.com` died as a search engine a long time ago. However, you can still submit a website's sitemap to it, if you wish. However, it will have to be done manually. If you'd like to submit your XML sitemap to `Ask.com`, simply type in the following in your browser's search bar: `http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=http%3A//www.example.com/sitemap.xml`, where `example` is your domain name.