# Yahoo sitemap ping URL?

Tags: sitemap, yahoo

We recently used the URL:

```
http://search.yahooapis.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/updateNotification?appid=YahooDemo&url=....
```

To ping Yahoo about sitemap changes. This URL turned out to time out and is not reachable.

Then I googled and on the Yahoo site I found a different URL which also times out:

```
http://search.yahooapis.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/ping?sitemap=....
```

What is the correct address to ping Yahoo about sitemap changes?

Comment: Yahoo displays results from Bing, why do you want to ping Yahoo for sitemap changes?

Comment: @Zistoloen wow I didn't know that. Such information :-O Thanks!!

Comment: @Zistoloen Do you have a working URL for ask? `http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=` gives 404

Comment: Sorry, Ask has so few users than I only optimize SEO of my sites for Google and Bing.

Comment: For Ask see: [Ask.com sitemap crawler down (for good)?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31057/ask-com-sitemap-crawler-down-for-good) -- It is down for good because they "utilize a crawling method of adding new content to our search index".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is [Yahoo's documentation for their sitemap ping](https://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/V1/ping.html).  At the top there is a prominent notification that Yahoo webmaster tools have moved to Bing webmaster tools.

[image]

That is why the ping times out.  It is no longer supported and you should use Bing webmaster tools instead.

[Here are the instructions for submitting sitemaps to Bing](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4).  It includes the ping URL:

```
http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/sitemap.xml
```